# "Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type '

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums

i have integrated Objective C Frameworks to use in my Swift Projects .now in my objective c Frameworks i have some Enum decalred alraedy

```
e.g.

enum LE_DEVICE_STATE
    {
        LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED=0,
        LE_DEVICE_STATE_CONNECTING,
         LE_DEVICE_STATE_CONNECTED,
        LE_DEVICE_STATE_UPDATING_FIRMWARE
    };
```

but now when i try to use this enum in switch case its not allowing me in swift and throwing an error

> "Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'LE_DEVICE_STATE' and '(LE_DEVICE_STATE)'"

.so can anyone please guide me how can i write this code?

i have tried to do following

```
switch (theDevice.state) {

            case LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                self.btnConnect.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            case LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            self.btnConnect.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        case LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            self.btnConnect.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        case LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            self.btnConnect.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


            default:
            self.btnConnect.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


        }
```

Comment: use ==== switch theDevice.state {.....} instead of switch (theDevice.state) {....}

Comment: nope its not working

Answer (score 5):

If the Objective-C enumeration were defined as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, LE_DEVICE_STATE) {
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED=0,
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_CONNECTING,
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_CONNECTED,
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_UPDATING_FIRMWARE
};
```

then it is imported as a Swift `enum`, and you can do

```
switch(theDevice.state) {
case .DISCONNECTED:
    // ...
}
```

If you have to keep it as

```
enum LE_DEVICE_STATE
{
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED=0,
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_CONNECTING,
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_CONNECTED,
    LE_DEVICE_STATE_UPDATING_FIRMWARE
};
```

then it is imported as a `struct` and you can compare it with `.value`:

```
switch(theDevice.state.value) {
case LE_DEVICE_STATE_DISCONNECTED.value:
    // ...;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I you want direct compatibility between Obj-C and Swift enums, then the Obj-C enum must be declared using `NS_ENUM`. For plain C (Obj-C) enums use `.value`.